# recognize in which vector the cursor is using an inclinated vector

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a condition to know in which vector my cursor is, so I tried to illustrate with an image, imagine it's a tablet:

[image: inclined vector]

So I need a code to know in which vector the cursor is (not coordinates) when the event ACTION.DOWN. I know I must use if conditions and some formula but can't get into it.

Comment: thanks Ted Hopp for pasting my image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say that the coordinates of the action down event are (x, y) and the rectangle extends from (0, 0) at the top left to (w, h) at the bottom right. You can classify the event using the following formulas (derived by taking the cross product of (x, y) with (w, h) and of [(x, y) - (w, 0)] with [(0, h) - (w, 0)]:

- x*h - y*w — if this is positive, then (x,y) is *above* the major diagonal
- w*h - x*h - y*w — if this is positive, then (x,y) is *above* the minor diagonal

Thus, if the event is above both diagonals, it is closest to vector 1; if it is above the major diagonal but below the minor diagonal, it is closest to vector 2; etc.

Comment: well i did the calculations, and works perfectly, now i'll put it into my code, a lot of thanks @Ted Hopp

Answer (score 0):

First, find the slope(`y/x`) from the center to the corner of the screen. Then find the slope from the center to the cursor. Compare the absolute values.

If the cursor slope is higher than the corner slope, you're in sections 1/3. Otherwise, you're in 2/4. A simple check for what side of the center is on will determine which from there.

For example, if the cursor slope is higher than the corner's, and the cursor is above the center, you're in section 1.